# Different behavior of mpiexec in Windows and in Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, mpi, gfortran

I have a code in Fortran (program.f) and I have compiled it with Eclipse in \ubuntu 16 and in Windows 7.

The Eclipse configuration for Ubuntu is the follow:

```
GNU Fortran Compiler: gfortran
Include paths(-l)   : /usr/lib/openmpi/include
GNU Fortran Linker  : mpif90
Tool Chain Editor   : GCC Fortran
```

The Eclipse configuration for Windows is the follow:

```
GNU Fortran Compiler: gfortran
Include paths(-l)   : C:\cygwin64\usr\include
GNU Fortran Linker  : mpif90
Tool Chain Editor   : GCC Fortran
```

When I execute the program in Ubuntu, the program works how it is expected.
In Ubuntu the program is executed with 2 processors by doing

```
$ mpiexec -np 2 myprogram
```

And the behavior is the follow

```
$ mpiexec -np 2 myprogram 
 There are            2  processors running this job.
 Rank#           1 d1=           65  d2=          128
 Rank#           0 d1=            1  d2=           64
```

Where d1 and d2 are pieces of the problem domain assigned to each processors. In this example the total domain is 128. The domain was assigned from 1 to 64 to processor 0, and from 65 to 128 to processor 1. This is the expected behavior: the model of 128 are divided in 2, from 1 to 64 to processor 0, and from 65 to 128 for the processor 1.

For the other hand, in Windows, after compile the code using the mentioned  specifications, I execute the program by doing:

```
$ mpiexec.exe -n 2 myprogram.exe
```

And the behavior is the follow

```
$ mpiexec -np 2 myprogram 
 There are            1  processors running this job.
 Rank#           0 d1=            1  d2=          128
 Rank#           0 d1=            1  d2=          128
```

We can see that the behavior is different: the program executed in Windows is not running in parallel as it is expected. In the terminal we can see that 1 processor is running the program, and the domain is assigned as follow: from 1 to 128 (whole domain) to processor 0 and, from 1 to 128 (whole domain again?) to processor 0. ***This is the problem that I am trying to solve***. I am trying to have the same behavior that I have in Ubuntu.

The *mpiexec.exe* program for Windows was obtained from the official installer [MS-MPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/message-passing-interface/microsoft-mpi).

The *gfortran* and the *OpenMPI* libs for Windows were obtained by using *[cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)*

I tried to change the GNU linker and the compiler in Eclipse for Windows and does not work. I tried to run the code in others machines with Windows 10 and problem is the same.

Any suggestions on how to try solve this issue?

Comment: Pleaae do nit use the javascript snippet for other languages. Use the `{}` button or three ```

Comment: @VladimirF you are right, it will be corrected soon, thanks

Comment: Your issue is quite common when compiling MPI program. You are most probably compiling your software on Windows using an MPI implementation (in your case, I think it is OpenMPI) and you are executing it with another MPI implementation (most likely MS-MPI). In order to fix your issue on Windows, you should be coherent with respect to the MPI implementation you are using to compile and the one you are using to run your parallel program.

Comment: @jcgiret yes, it is right, the implementation is OpenMPI and the execution is over MS-MPI. And it is because I did not find the OpenMPI implementation to run the code in Windows. Let me be try to be consistent and check. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @jcgiret there are a consistency problem: the program is compiled using OpenMPI and it is executed with MS-MPI.
To solve this issue the code was executed using the equivalent to *mpiexec* defined in the [*openmpi*](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fopenmpi%2Fopenmpi-3.1.1-2&grep=openmpi) package:

```
usr/bin/mpiexec -> orterun.exe
```

The program is executed in windows by

```
$ orterun.exe -n 2 myprogram.exe
```

Then the results is the same that obtained in Ubuntu:

```
$ orterun.exe -n 2 myprogram.exe 
There are            2  processors running this job.
Rank#           1 d1=           65  d2=          128
Rank#           0 d1=            1  d2=           64
```